# xubuntu 20.04 MenuLibre Other not shown

Tags: xubuntu, 20.04, menulibre

This is a virgin install of 20.04, not upgrading from 18.04 and previous versions. I tried to add an item to Other using MenuLibre. Launcher tested OK, saved, etc., yet Whisker menu still not showing "Other" category. If I go back to MenuLibre it does not even show my addition. Yet, in my $HOME all changes and the launcher file is created. I researched the subject, consulted answer here "How to reset MenuLibre"; purged, deleted related files, reinstalled MenuLibre, but nothing helps. This really baffles me.

Further notes a few days later:
After various attempts finally I have the "Other" category in Whisker menu with my custom added menu items (launchers). However, I had to do it "under the hood" and not with MenuLibre. Here is how:

1. deleted `~/.config/menus/applications-merged` and `~/.config/menus/gnome-applications-merged` folders
2. created my launchers (.desktop files) in `~/.local/share/applications/` with Mousepad, according to relevant specs
3. edited `~/.config/menus/xfce-applications.menu` XML file with Mousepad in the `<Name>Other</Name>` section within `<layout>` part by adding there `<Filename>MyOwnLauncher.desktop</Filename>` lines of my own Other menu items.

This seems to work. Maybe tedious, but not as frustrating as MenuLibre. I even created a new user to see if MenuLibre would work there - but not really. Same thing, Other is not shown. The new menu item in the other category is in fact created in `~/.config/menus/applications-merged` as .desktop files, but invisible to Whisker menu.

Could this be a **bug** in MenuLibre for the 20.04 xUbuntu version?